# Affine space independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Let K = Z$_p$ , V = K$^n$ and let W be a m-dimensional subspace in V.

We define a set H = $\alpha$ + W = { $\alpha$ + $\gamma$ |  $\gamma \in W $} (I'm not sure what do we call it in English, a layer?)

Question : How many H's are there in V?

Attempt : Let's assume m < n (if m=n then there is just one H). Then we know that we can define L such that V = L $\bigoplus$ W. L consists of $\alpha$ 's which we plug in our formula. We do not require L to consist of linearly independent vectors but we are constrained by finite field. Therefore there would be p$^n (p-1)^n ... (p-m)^n$ H's. Is that correct or am I at least moving in the right direction?

Comment: It's called an affine subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\bigl\{\alpha+W\mid\alpha\in V\bigr\}= V/W\simeq L\simeq \mathbf F_p^{n-m}$$
hence there are $p^{n-m}$ such affine subspaces.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's good to know the translation also :)